# WordPress deja de funcionar con enlaces permanentes

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Configure un servidor desde cero dedicado a WordPress al momento de intentar habilitar los enlaces permanentes el sitio se cae y deja de responder.

Ya intente de todo en el campo que gestiona los enlaces del sitio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi `.htaccess`                                                                                      .htaccess

```
# BEGIN LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
RewriteEngine on
CacheLookup on
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:no-autoflush]
RewriteRule \.litespeed_conf\.dat - [F,L]

### marker CACHE RESOURCE start ###
RewriteRule wp-content/.*/[^/]*(responsive|css|js|dynamic|loader|fonts)\.php - [E=cache-control:max-age=3600]
### marker CACHE RESOURCE end ###

### marker FAVICON start ###
RewriteRule favicon\.ico$ - [E=cache-control:max-age=86400]
### marker FAVICON end ###

### marker DROPQS start ###
CacheKeyModify -qs:fbclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:gclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:utm*
CacheKeyModify -qs:_ga
### marker DROPQS end ###

</IfModule>
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END NON_LSCACHE
# BEGIN WordPress
# Las directivas (líneas) entre "BEGIN WordPress" y "END WordPress" son
# generadas dinámicamente y solo deberían ser modificadas mediante filtros de WordPress.
# Cualquier cambio en las directivas que hay entre esos marcadores serán sobrescritas.

# END WordPress
```

La ruta en apache es `/var/www/html/sitio`

La carpeta ya tiene permisos 777 para descartar problemas por alguna restricción

Tengo activado el modo `rewrite_module (shared)`
Fue activado con el comando sudo `a2enmod rewrite`

Alguien podría tener alguna idea de que puede ser el problema

Comment: Duda: Por qué pones algo de la DB y del `.htaccess`?? Esos enlaces se gestionan en `https://tupagina.es/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`. Ahí estas configurándolos o es algo de lo que no me he enterado?

Comment: Correcto se pueden configurar esos parámetros desde el panel de administrador, sin embargo, esos parámetros se guardan en la DB

Comment: Se que eso se guarda en la DB. Esa no fue mi pregunta, pero ok.